# Auto Zoom in for a cluster of map markers

Tags: ios, skmaps

I have multiple map views and each view has a group of map markers

e.g. Map View 1 = 4 map markers, Map View 2 = 10 map markers, Map View 3 = 20 map markers.

In most instances the map markers are a few meters from each other and in other instances they are a few miles apart.

Is there an easy way to set the Map View such that it automatically zooms in such that it encompasses the map markers in each view. If i have to do it manually no amount of zoom level will never be perfect.

An alternative is to define a center and a custom zoom level for each map view but that sounds a bit tedious.

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic function for doing this - you can calculate the bounding box corresponding to the POI cluster (i.e. find the top left lat and long and bottom right lat and long) and zoom to that bounding box.

Comment: Thanks - the developer who is working on my iOS map is currently centering around a lat & long and then using a zoom level to zoom in but the challenge is how does one calculate the zoom level as it would vary based on how distributed the cluster is SKMapView
var region = SKCoordinateRegion()
region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude-bottomRightCoord.latitude)*0.5
        region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude-topLeftCoord.longitude)*0.5
        region.zoomLevel = 5
        
        mapView.visibleRegion = region